# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'formData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. what is dependency is use

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When is set value but there is missing dependency add the formData in dependency then is will go infinity loop

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (id !== 0) {
        profileByID(id).then((res) => {
            const data = res.data.result;
            setTimeout(() => {
                setFormData({
                    ...formData,
                    firstName: data.firstName,
                    lastName: data.lastName,
                    email: data.email,
                });
                setbirthDate(new Date(data.birthDate));
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
    console.log(true);
  }, [id, profileByID]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is going into infinity loop because whenever you update your form value using setFormData it triggers a render which in turn again calls useEffect method. This is happening because you are setting a new object every time using setFormData.

let obj={a: 1,b:2}

obj==={...,a:1} //False

i.e. They are not the same so setting setFormData like this will always cause rerender and will lead to infinity loop. This is just basic illustration of how useFormData is comparing data behind the scenes.
So to solve this problem use different useState for all different things example

const[firstName, setFirstName]= useState('')

const[lastName, setLastName]= useState('')

const[email, setEmail]= useState('')

and so on..

or use the useReducer approach if there are lots of data, there are many blogs from where you can go through the useReducer apporach

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to turn this into a functional update :

```
setFormData(formData => ({
  ...formData,
  firstName: data.firstName,
  lastName: data.lastName,
  email: data.email,
}));
```

Then you don't need to put `formData` in the dependency array.